# Counting the array keys values

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this code that takes a file and outputs the array like I need it to but, I would like to be able to count how many times `st` and `city`, and then output it like this

```
// atanta, ga, 5
// new albany, ny, 10  
// green bay, wi, 3 
// ...
```

Here is the code I have that that makes the file an array:

```
  <?php
  $array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('PrintHistory.csv'));
  $my_array = array();
  $new_header = array("Print Date","Cost","Recipient","City","State and Zip","Status","Tracking #/Insurance ID","Date Delivered","Carrier","Class Service","Special Services","Insured Value","Cost Code","Weight","Mail Date","Refund Type");

  $my_array[0] = $new_header;

  foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
     if( $key == 0 ) continue;

  $my_row = array();
  foreach ($row as $key2 => $value) {
      // if this is the recipient column
      if( $key2 == 2 ) {
         // explode the value
         $exp = explode(',', $value);
         // we insert a value in the 4 next column ("Recipient","PO BOX/Address","City","State and Zip")
         // we assume that the $exp[0] = recipient name; $exp[1] = po box/address; ...
    $address = '';
    $secondtolast = trim($exp[count($exp)-2]);
    $last = trim(end($exp));

    foreach($exp as $val){
        if( $val == $secondtolast || $val == $last ) continue;
          $address = $address . $val;
    }

    array_push($my_row, $address, $secondtolast, $last);

  }
  else array_push($my_row, $value);
  }

  array_push($my_array, $my_row);
  }


  echo "<pre>";  
  print_r($my_array); 
  echo "</pre>";

  die();
```

And here is some of the array to look at:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1/20/2016
        [1] => $8.15
        [2] => Jon Los Batos PO BOX 1232 BLANCO TX 78606-1232
        [3] => BLANCO
        [4] => TX 78606-1232
        [5] => Printed
        [6] => ="940551488859"
        [7] => 
        [8] => USPS
        [9] => Priority Mail (R)
        [10] => USPS Tracking
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 1lb 8oz
        [14] => 1/20/2016
        [15] => E-refund
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1/20/2016
        [1] => $8.15
        [2] => Kia Bennings PO BOX 2446 BLANCO TX 78606-1232
        [3] => BLANCO
        [4] => TX 78606-1232
        [5] => Printed
        [6] => ="9405511899563827"
        [7] => 
        [8] => USPS
        [9] => Priority Mail (R)
        [10] => USPS Tracking
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 1lb 8oz
        [14] => 1/20/2016
        [15] => E-refund
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1/20/2016
        [1] => $8.92
        [2] => Bavis lynn PO BOX 196 P.O. BOX 196 WESTCLIFFE CO 81252-1696
        [3] => WESTCLIFFE
        [4] => CO 81252-1696
        [5] => Printed
        [6] => ="9405563388113621"
        [7] => 
        [8] => USPS
        [9] => Priority Mail (R)
        [10] => USPS Tracking
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 1lb 8oz
        [14] => 1/20/2016
        [15] => E-refund
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1/20/2016
        [1] => $10.77
        [2] => Ally Hudson PSC 4845 BOX 3734 FPO AP 96321-0004
        [3] => FPO
        [4] => AP 96321-0004
        [5] => Printed
        [6] => ="9405511899563388396642"
        [7] => 
        [8] => USPS
        [9] => Priority Mail (R)
        [10] => USPS Tracking
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 1lb 8oz
        [14] => 1/20/2016
        [15] => E-refund
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1/20/2016
        [1] => $6.60
        [2] => Bark Heinteman PO BOX 2369 CHARLOTTE COURT HOUSE VA 23923-0269
        [3] => CHARLOTTE COURT HOUSE
        [4] => VA 23923-0269
        [5] => Printed
        [6] => ="940551189950145"
        [7] => 
        [8] => USPS
        [9] => Priority Mail (R)
        [10] => USPS Tracking
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 1lb 8oz
        [14] => 1/20/2016
        [15] => E-refund
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this code right after you have built *$my_array*:

```
// count cities
$summary = array();
foreach($my_array as $element) {
    $key = $element[3] . ", " . explode(" ", $element[4])[0];
    $summary[$key] = isset($summary[$key]) ? $summary[$key] + 1 : 1;
}

// print summary
foreach($summary as $city => $count) {
    echo "$city, $count<br>";
}
```

With the *$my_array* content you provided, you would get this output:

> BLANCO, TX, 2
>   WESTCLIFFE, CA, 1
>   FPO, AP, 1
>   CHARLOTTE COURT HOUSE, VA, 1

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, and this worked just like I need it to, thank you.

Comment: Do you know how I would export this count to an csv file? So city is the first column header, st next column, and count last column?

Comment: Use *fputcsv*. Here is an [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#example-2627). If you need help with that, please ask a new question. These comment sections are not suitable to do follow-up questions.

Comment: So I tried to finish it but it is just not outputting it right, can you please look at my other question?

Comment: Can you post a link to your other question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002132/how-to-take-my-count-and-export-it-to-a-csv

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try ?

```
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', file('PrintHistory.csv'));

$my_array = array();

$new_header = array("Print Date", "Cost", "Recipient", "City", "State and Zip", "Status", "Tracking #/Insurance ID", "Date Delivered", "Carrier", "Class Service", "Special Services", "Insured Value", "Cost Code", "Weight", "Mail Date", "Refund Type");

$my_array[0] = $new_header;
$cities = array(); // cities to count.
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $my_row = array();
    foreach ($row as $key2 => $value) {
        // if this is the recipient column
        if ($key2 == 2) {
            // explode the value
            $exp = explode(',', $value);
            // we insert a value in the 4 next column ("Recipient","PO BOX/Address","City","State and Zip")
            // we assume that the $exp[0] = recipient name; $exp[1] = po box/address; ...
            $address = '';
            $secondtolast = trim($exp[count($exp) - 2]);
            $last = trim(end($exp));

            foreach ($exp as $val) {
                if ($val == $secondtolast || $val == $last) {
                    continue;
                }

                $address = $address . $val;
            }

            array_push($my_row, $address, $secondtolast, $last);

        } else {
            array_push($my_row, $value);
        }
        $cities[] = $my_row[3] . ', ' . $my_row[4]; // adding cities to it
    }

    array_push($my_array, $my_row);
}
// count and calculate multiple occurences
$cityCounts = array_count_values($cities));
$citiesMultipleAppears = array();
foreach ($cityCounts as $k => $v) {
    if ($v > 1) {
        $citiesMultipleAppears[] = $k . ', ' . $v;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_array);
print_r($citiesMultipleAppears);
echo "</pre>";
```